# React Native, unable to update value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to update the value of title but it's not updating the value can someone tell me whats going on
EditPost.js

```
class EditScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior="position"
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0 : 100}
      >
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={this.props.navigation.getParam("image")}
        />

        <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
          <AppTextInput
            value={this.props.navigation.getParam("title")}
            conChangeText={(text) =>
              this.props.navigation.setParams({ title: text })
            }
          />
          <AppTextInput value={this.props.navigation.getParam("des")} />
        </View>
        <AppButton
          text="Save"
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.getParam("onEdit");
            this.props.navigation.goBack();
          }}
        />
```

home.js

```
 onEdit = (data) => {
    const newPosts = this.state.post.map((item) => {
      if (item.key === data.key) return data;
      else return item;
    });
    this.setState({ post: newPosts, editMode: false });
  };
```

Can some help me please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, anyways why you are not using useState instead ?

```
<AppTextInput
            value={this.props.navigation.getParam("title")}
            conChangeText={(text) => --> typo, should be onChangeText ?
              this.props.navigation.setParams({ title: text })
            }
/>
```

Comment: someone corrected it and i marked his ans too :/ anyway thnx for help, I'm not using useState bcoz i'm not using function base

Comment: state then it is the way I guess but is your choice good luck

Comment: well it's letting me to change text but not updating it after clicking save

Comment: i will add function that handling onEdit in home screen